# how to access control of a webpage that is loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript

I created a web application for loading web page with iframe and i loaded a webpage into that iframe.Can i access the control of web page from iframe using javascript.The page loaded is in another domain.

Comment: Consider providing more details.

Comment: Does the page loaded into the iFrame is of the same web application or domain?

Comment: The page loaded is in another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply. You can't. Please refer into [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or StackOverFlow [364952](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Is there any way to push our value to the controls of  third party webpage?

Comment: Browser modification, maybe Greasemonkey plugin for FF

Comment: From project page: `Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.
Hundreds of scripts, for a wide variety of popular sites, are already available at http://userscripts.org.
You can write your own scripts, too. Check out http://wiki.greasespot.net/ to get started.`

Comment: Is there any control like webBrowser to load third party webpage.When i tried webBrowser control it fails to load the webpage.Some part of webpage is in hidden state.